# GDB Python API: How to access events in Python

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to write a Python script for GDB that uses the events  gdb.events.inferior_call_pre and events.inferior_call_post.  However, those events are not defined in gdb.events:

```
>(gdb) python print(dir(gdb.events))
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'cont', 'exited', 'new_objfile', 'stop']
```

The above was done without a program loaded.  I have also loaded a C program, run it until a breakpoint, and then executed the command with the same result.

I am running CentOS 7 with gdb 7.6.1.

I downloaded and compiled the source (with --with-python=yes) for gdb 7.12 with less success:

```
(gdb) python print(dir(gdb.events))
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'gdb' is not defined
Error while executing Python code.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to gdb's [NEWS](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=HEAD) file, support for the events `gdb.events.inferior_call_pre` and `gdb.events.inferior_call_post` was added in gdb 7.9.

If you're compiling gdb from source, the `gdb` python module can be found in the directory `gdb-7.12.1/gdb/python/lib/gdb`, which gets copied to `gdb-7.12.1/gdb/data-directory/python/gdb`.

When you do `make install`, it gets copied to `<prefix directory>/share/gdb/python/gdb`.

If the latter directory can't be found at runtime - for instance, if you run gdb from the source directory without having done `make install` - gdb ought to complain at startup:

```
$ ./gdb
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb: 
./gdb: warning: 
Could not load the Python gdb module from `<prefix directory>/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.
```

The data directory also contains files with lists of available system calls for various target architectures. It's worth making sure that gdb has access to it.

If you can't run `make install` but have to run gdb directly from the source directory, cd to `gdb-7.12.1/gdb` and run `./gdb --data-directory=./data-directory` .

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  I want to add that when specifying --data-directory, gdb looks in a subdirectory called python, so specifying _--data-directory=./python/lib/gdb_ won't work.    To get it to work in my build directory, I created a symlink.  So  I ran:   `ln -s ./python/lib ./python/python` then `./gdb --data-directory=./python`

Comment: If you can't run `make install` before running gdb from the source directory, you can run `./gdb --data-directory=./data-directory` . This will give gdb access to some needed python classes as well as the architecture's system call list (for the `catch syscall` command). I'll add that to the answer.